# When using importlib to load a module, can I put it in a package without an __init__.py file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic, python-import

My Python application loads plugins from a user-specified path (which is not part of `sys.path`), according to [the importlib documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importing-a-source-file-directly):

```
import importlib.util
import sys

def load_module(module_name, file_path):
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, file_path)
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    sys.modules[module_name] = module
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
    return module

plugin_module = load_module("some_plugin", "/path/to/plugins/some_plugin.py")
```

To make it possible for the user to factor out common functionality between multiple plugins, I want to allow relative imports in the plugins:

```
from . import plugin_common

def plugin_function(x):
    return plugin_common.something(x)
```

When implemented like this, I get an ImportError in the plugin:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

To my understanding, this is because the `some_plugin` module [is not considered part of a package](https://peps.python.org/pep-0328/#relative-imports-and-name), and relative imports can therefore not be used (inside `some_plugin.py`, `__name__` is `'some_plugin'` and `__package__` is empty).

I can solve this by first loading the surrounding package and then putting the imported module into that package:

```
load_module("plugins_package", "/path/to/plugins/__init__.py")
plugin_module = load_module("plugins_package.some_plugin", "/path/to/plugins/some_plugin.py")
```

Now, `__name__` is `'plugins_package.some_plugin'`, `__package__` is `'plugins_package'`, and I can use relative imports.

However, this requires the user to put an (empty) `__init__.py` file in the plugins directory, which I would like to avoid. Since normal packages don't require an `__init__.py` file (they will be treated as a [namespace packages](https://peps.python.org/pep-0420/)), it seems like this should be possible.

It seems like it should be possible to create a namespace package dynamically (using `importlib`) for `plugins_package` and using that as package for the imported `plugin_module`. But I haven't found a way to do this.

So:

- Can I create a namespace package (where I can put `plugin_module` in) dynamically?
- Can I dynamically create a normal package without the need for an `__init__.py` file?
- Am I on the wrong track and there is a better way to achieve what I want (relative imports in a module loaded dynamically from outside `sys.path`)?

Comment: `import_module` lets you provide an optional second argument to specify the parent package. `__init__.py` is rarely, if ever, necessary since the introduction of namespace packages.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `importlib.import_module` is for importing a module by module name, not by file name (importing by file name is what I am looking for).

Comment: A lazy solution would be to create the `__init__.py` file yourself (in the user-provided folder) so you can later expect it to be there, but it is prone to permission errors.